# Number of operations in google adwords api calls

Tags: google-ads-api

If I want to change bids of 5 keywords in an Adgroup, then does it cost me 5 operations or is there a way to do it in lesser number of operations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I have found the answer. It would cost me 5 operations and there is no way to reduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the answer. It would cost me 5 operations and there is no way to reduce this.